# Traverse the `filesystem::path` more intuitively?

Tags: c++, path

```cpp
auto mpath = 
std::filesystem::path(SDL_GetBasePath());
    std::cout << mpath.parent_path().parent_path().parent_path() << 
std::endl;
```

My goal is to jump up 2 directories using the `filesystem::path` header in C++17.
Is there a way to traverse the `filesystem::path` more intuitively?
Other than getting the parent N number of times.

Comment: You can add `../..` to the path instead. This way it will refer to double parent path. You can also call `weakly_canonical` in case you don't want to see any weird operations in the path.

Comment: `std::cout << mpath << std::endl;
  std::cout << mpath / "../.." << std::endl;`
This Worked thanks!